# dynamically assign image src to a canvas

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

I am trying to initialize a php variable to image source gotten from a database loop. this is the snippet of code I am using to do that

```
<?php foreach($load_preview as $item): ?>
    <div class="store-item">
        <?php var imgSrc = base_url()."thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>//having syntaxt error at this line
            <a href="<?php echo site_url()."/"."accessories/preview/".$item["id"];?>">
                <canvas width="450" height="450" id="canvas">Sorry, no canvas available</canvas>    
            </a>    
        </div>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am reassigning the above into a javascript code code to draw a canvas for zooming as shown

```
/**
 * START
 */
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
    iw = 500;
    ih = 500;
    canvas.width = (iw / 2 - 1.5)|0; //compensate for rounding errors
    canvas.height = (ih / 2 - 1.5)|0;
    doCanvas();
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', doCanvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
}
img.src = "<?php echo imgSrc ?>";//retrieve the assigned variable here in the javascript assignment


</script>
```

this looks a little bit confusing to me. can someone please assist

Comment: In php variables are preceeded by a `$` sign. Talking about this: `<?php var imgSrc = base_url()`

Comment: `<?php var imgSrc = base_url()."thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>` should be `<?php $imgSrc = base_url()."thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>`

Comment: ok. so how can I retrieve the variable in javascript block 
img.src = "<?php echo imgSrc ?>";

Comment: Just told you that. Use `$` before every variable in php. (here - `<?php echo imgSrc ?>`)

Comment: only one image is been returned from the looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
<?php var imgSrc = base_url()."thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>
```

It probably should be like this:

```
var imgSrc = '<?php echo base_url()."thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>';
```

Comment: var imgSrc returns mispelled word

Comment: @parker I'm sorry, I don't quote get what you mean?

Comment: but the looping is done in different code block from the javascript

Comment: In PHP you don't initialize a variable with `var`, so you're going to have to change that line in any case. Fix it first and then if you're still having problem try to describe them with as much detail as possible.

Comment: @parker you have to apply Schlaus' patch to the php script which generates your javascript code, probably on the same page where the html code is generated.